# How to Move an object using css

Tags: html, css, header

Please help me to move object on top. i used margin-top but not work.

CSS

```
    section#features .center-box{
    display:block;
    background-color:#22a3df;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    padding:10px;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top:13px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="center-box">
    <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
</div>
```

[image: How to move an obeject to top]

Comment: can you please add your code or demo so its better to understand

Answer (score 1):

Add parent class to the container element and child class to the element that you wish to move further top.

```
.parent{
  position:relative;
}

.child{
  position:absolute;
  top: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `top` not `margin-top`

add margin-top

```
section#features .center-box{
    display:block;
    background-color:#22a3df;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    padding:10px;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    margin: 13px auto 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First give your div position then use top to positioning it:

```
.center-box{
display:block;
background-color:#22a3df;
transform: rotate(45deg);
padding:10px;
width:40px;
height:40px;
margin: 0 auto;
position:Relative;
top:13px;}
```